# Transform a Pandas series to be monotonic

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'm looking for a way to remove the points that ruin the monotonicity of a series.

For example

```
s = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,10,4,5,6])
```

or

```
s = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,-1,4,5,6])
```

we would extract

```
s = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

> *NB: we assume that the first element is always correct.*

Comment: x=[0,1,2,3,10,4,5,6]                                                                                                                   s = pd.Series(x)                                                                                                                     
Can we modify making a list like this ?

Comment: I don't know that this problem is fully specified.  For `[0,1,2,3,10,4,5,6]`, 10 doesn't break monotonicity; 4 (and 5, 6) does.  Why do you expect to remove 10?

Comment: For my data, the serie is energy consumption so we know it should be increasing. Sometimes there are errors in the data that give points not folowing the increasing trend. That's what we want to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monotonic could be both increasing or decreasing, the functions below will return exclude all values that brean monotonicity.

However, there seems to be a confusion in your question, given the series `s = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,10,4,5,6])`, `10` doesn't break monotonicity conditions, `4, 5, 6` do. So the correct answer there is `0, 1, 2, 3, 10`

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,10,4,5,6])

def to_monotonic_inc(s):
    return s[s >= s.cummax()]

def to_monotonic_dec(s):
    return s[s <= s.cummin()]

print(to_monotonic_inc(s))
print(to_monotonic_dec(s))
```

Output is `0, 1, 2, 3, 10` for increasing and `0` for decreasing.

Perhaps you want to find the *longest* monotonic array? because that's a completely different search problem.

----- EDIT -----

Below is a simple way of finding the *longest* monotonic ascending array given your constraints using plain python:

```
def get_longeset_monotonic_asc(s):
    enumerated = sorted([(v, i) for i, v in enumerate(s) if v >= s[0]])[1:]
    output = [s[0]]
    last_index = 0
    for v, i in enumerated:
        if i > last_index:
            last_index = i
            output.append(v)

    return output

s1 = [0,1,2,3,10,4,5,6]
s2 = [0,1,2,3,-1,4,5,6]

print(get_longeset_monotonic_asc(s1))
print(get_longeset_monotonic_asc(s2))

'''
Output:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

'''
```

Note that this solution involves sorting which is *O(nlog(n))* + a second step which is *O(n)*.

Comment: For my data, the serie is energy consumption so we know it should be increasing. Sometimes there are errors in the data that give points not folowing the increasing trend. That's what we want to remove. its the 10 in this case.

Comment: I think monotonicity is not the right approach for what you want to achieve. Is your data linear? polynomial? Instead of looking for monotonicity I would perform some polynomial regression and drop outliers (points that are too far away from the resulting curve).

Comment: The data is simply increasing as it's an energy measurement, droping outliers after a linear regression would work but looks like an advanced solution for a simple problem.

Comment: It's not that simple, as suggested in my answer, another approach may be finding the *longest* monotonic ascending array which is may be a little bit trickier than computing a linear regression. I think finding the longest monotonic array is a *O(n log(n))* problem.

Comment: @melfaiz I have edited my answer with a second solution that should work for you use case. (Maybe not the most efficient though)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to produce a monotonically increasing series:

```
import pandas as pd

# create data
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

# find max so far (i.e., running_max)
df = pd.concat([s.rename('orig'), 
                s.cummax().rename('running_max'),
               ], axis=1)

# are we at or above max so far?
df['keep?'] = (df['orig'] >= df['running_max'])

# filter out one or many points below max so far
df = df.loc[ df['keep?'], 'orig']

# verify that remaining points are monotonically increasing
assert pd.Index(df).is_monotonic_increasing

# print(df.drop_duplicates()) # eliminates ties
print(df)                     # keeps ties

0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
10    5 # <-- same as previous value -- a tie
11    6
12    7
13    8
Name: orig, dtype: int64
```

You can see graphically with `s.plot();` and `df.plot();`