# Transform Pandas series to monotonically increreasing with forward fill

Tags: python, pandas, series

I would like to transform a non-monotonically increasing Pandas Series to a monotonically increasing one.
Quite similarly to [Transform a Pandas series to be monotonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63638511/transform-a-pandas-series-to-be-monotonic)
but instead dropping of decreasing values, replacing them with the previous value. Similarly to DataFrame.fillna(method='ffill').

Basically, I would like to vectorise (preferably with Pandas) the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([0,1,2,2,3,2,4,2,3,5])
f,a = plt.subplots()
s.plot(ax=a, alpha=0.5, linestyle='steps-mid')
for i in range(s.size-1):
    j=i+1
    if s.iat[j] < s.iat[i] :
        s.iat[j] = s.iat[i]
s.plot(ax=a, linestyle='steps-mid')
```

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in luck my friend. There is already a pandas method just for you!

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,1,2,2,3,2,4,2,3,5]})
df['A'] = pd.DataFrame.cummax(df.A)
```

Enjoy!